# Export PDF, Can I provide two ranges?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this code to export a sheet as a PDF.

```
{var url_ext = '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'  
      
      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId))
      + (shRng ? ('&range=A1:L43') : null)
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=A4'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw = true' // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
      }
```

Is there a way to provide two ranges and have them export in the same PDF but on different pages? [image: Invoice]

The reason for this is I want to send the entire spreadsheet shown in the image, but I want columns M-Z to appear on a different page. Right now, I can give 1 range (A1:L43) and it prints fine.

OR maybe there is a way to insert a page break, change the scale of the table before exporting, eg. a different way of separating the table into two pages of the same PDF that someone can recommend.

Comment: Try putting the ranges in a temporary sheet export it and then delete it.

Comment: @Cooper Can you provide some code to show how I would try this? Thank you.

Comment: I could but if I did then you would never learn how to do it on your own.  Try doing it on your own at first.  Then ask specific focused questions when you run into trouble.

Comment: @Cooper just so I understand correctly, I should try putting the data contained within one range into a temp sheet and then export it? I am confused as to why I need a temp sheet.

Comment: you said that you already have code that exports a sheet to pdf so create a temp sheet or if you want to keep the same sheet and just clear it each time.  The put all of the data from your desired ranges on to that sheet and export it to pdf

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to export different ranges from a certain sheet to a PDF file (where data from each range should be in a different page).

If that's the case, and assuming that the ranges are in the active sheet, you can do the following:

- Create a temporary spreadsheet, which will be used to export the data to PDF (use [SpreadsheetApp.create(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname)).
- For each desired range notation (in this case, I think the ranges are `A1:L43` and `M1:Z43`), create a temporary sheet and copy the range to that sheet, using [insertSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet()) and [Range.copyTo(range)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)).
- Copy each temporary sheet (containing data from each range) to the temporary spreadsheet, using [Sheet.copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)).
- Delete the temporary sheets, using [deleteSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleteSheet(Sheet)).
- Export the temporary spreadsheet to PDF. In the sample below, I'm adding the exported PDF to Drive, using [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) and [DriveApp.createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob).
- Delete the temporary spreadsheet, using the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) (**you have to enable it via `Resources > Advanced Google Services...`. Otherwise, the last line in the provided script will throw an error**).

#### Code sample:

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function MULTIPLE_RANGES_TO_PDF() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const tempSS = SpreadsheetApp.create("Temporary Spreadsheet");
  const sourceSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rangeNotations = ["A1:L43", "M1:Z43"];
  rangeNotations.forEach(rangeNotation => {
    const sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(rangeNotation);
    const tempSheet = ss.insertSheet();
    sourceRange.copyTo(tempSheet.getRange("A1"));
    tempSheet.copyTo(tempSS);
    ss.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
  });
  tempSS.deleteSheet(tempSS.getSheets()[0]); // Remove first sheet in temp (blank)
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + tempSS.getId() + "/export?mimeType=application/pdf";
  var params = {
    headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }
  }
  var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(pdf).setName("My exported PDF.pdf");
  Drive.Files.remove(tempSS.getId());
}
```